# How accept two kinds of clients on a serversocket?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am developing a server application that will basically forward commands and messages from one client to the other. Those clients are two different applications, though. One is an app on an Android device that serves as a "remote control" to the other.

When booting either of those applications, it will register with the online server, through sockets. Now, my question is: How will my server be able to tell what kind of client it is dealing with after `ServerSocket.accept()`ing it?

I've come up with two possible solutions:

1: Open two ServerSockets, on two different ports. One application connects to one port, the other application connects to the other.

2: After connecting, the client sends a String containing an identifier of what client they are.

There are probably way more (and better) solutions than these two though, so I'd like to know what you people prefer to do. I'm fairly certain that I'm not the first person to run into this dilemma. :)

Comment: actually your 2 solution are (IMHO) the best ones, and in that order, too. only thing i'd add would be to make the traffic http/text/xml/json based which would make things a lot easier (though bandwidth-intensive). another, 3rd option _might_ be to read the whole incoming packet into a buffer (assumming ti fits and it isnt a continous stream or something), try "parsing" it as the 1st protocol and, if it fails, try "parsing" as the 2nd, 3rd etc - but this is both ugly and assumes a packet cant fit more than one supported protocol

Comment: I would prefer the second alternative, preferably using the same protocol for all devices. However, I may not see the whole picture here(perhaps different protocols are necessary??).

Comment: Only two clients? If more, perhaps read up on the [publish/subscribe model](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ObserverJmsExample.html)